# Get history of everything I installed?

Tags: 14.04

I've made many install commands via the terminal over time, I forget what I installed and I want to uninstall some of them.

How can I get the history of everything I installed through the terminal, from beginning till now, ordered by date?

Comment: See https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/list-installed-packages-date-linux/

Answer (score 1):

You can check the package history logs reside at `/var/log/apt/`, you will get the names of all the packages installed/removed along with the commands that were used to do so. Moreover you will see the date of the operation too.

You will find the latest logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log` and older logs in gzipped format e.g. `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`, `/var/log/apt/history.log.2.gz` etc.

By the way, if you just want a list of all the packages currently installed (via `dpkg`) in the system, you can run:

```
dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1 > ~/installed_packages.txt
```

Now the file `installed_packages.txt` in your home directory will contain the list of all installed packages.